# How to use precompiled headers with gcc if linking against openmp

Tags: gcc, g++, openmp, precompiled-headers

Minimal example:

```
// file: main.cpp
#include "pch.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

--

```
// file: pch.h
#include <iostream>
```

Works fine and as expected if I compile this with

```
g++ pch.h
g++ main.cpp -Winvalid-pch
```

However once I change the last line to:

```
g++ main.cpp -fopenmp -Winvalid-pch
```

usage of the precompiled header is disabled:

```
warning: pch.h.gch: not used because `_REENTRANT' is defined [-Winvalid-pch]
```

How can I still use precompiled headers while linking to OpenMP? Why does the _REENTRANT define conflict with using a precompiled header at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must generate .pch and compile sources with identical flags.  `-fopenmp` implies `#pragma omp` and `-pthread`.

```
g++ -fopenmp pch.h
g++ main.cpp -fopenmp -Winvalid-pch
```

Or at least

```
g++ -pthread pch.h
g++ main.cpp -fopenmp -Winvalid-pch
```